# How to debug Jenkins error message "could not find a suitable ssh-agent provider"?

Tags: windows, git, ssh, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins on Win7 and i've installed tomcat for `ssh-agent` plugin. And I could clone my GitLab project via git bash via ssh.
But if I build the project by Jenkins, it always says :

```
[ssh-agent] Using credentials IliptonChen(APRTest)
[ssh-agent] Looking for ssh-agent implementation...
[ssh-agent] FATAL: Could not find a suitable ssh-agent provider
FATAL:[ssh-agent] Unable to start agent
```

[The full output text is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5gRgIfbXS2obGlSQUdsS0JGUDQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Related: [Running builds on slave nodes gives me Could not find a suitable ssh-agent provider error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33291078/55075).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the version of your [ssh-agent used by Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin).
This bug (for linux, but could apply to Windows too) reports (10 days ago, January 2014) this very same error message:
"[`JENKINS-20276`: Native Library Error after upgrading ssh-agent from 1.3 to 1.4](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20276)".

> Downgrading to 1.3 resolves the issue.

---

Update 2019, five years later: as commented, this should be fixed now.

`ssh-agent.exe` is part of a [Git for Windows distribution](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

```
D:\git\git>where ssh-agent.exe
D:\prgs\gits\current\usr\bin\ssh-agent.exe
```

(provided `path/to/git/usr/bin` is first in the `%PATH%` used by Jenkins)

Comment: Thanks, my ssh-agent plugin version is 1.4.1
And where can i found the 1.3 ?
I'm newbies about Jenkins.

Comment: @user2544979 since Jenkins doesn't allow easy downgrade (https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14530), you have to follow http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Downgrade-a-plugin-td375624.html, and copy the old hpi file over the current one (both for this plugin and https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Credentials+Plugin: 1.3 also): you need to respect that plugin dependency: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin#SSHAgentPlugin-Version1.3(20130809)

Comment: @user2544979 ssh-agent 1.3: https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-agent-plugin/releases/tag/ssh-agent-1.3 (from https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-agent-plugin/releases). Ssh credentials 1.3: https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-credentials-plugin/releases/tag/ssh-credentials-1.3 (from https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-credentials-plugin/releases)

Comment: Could I use GIT_SSH instead of ssh-agent ？

Comment: @user2544979 not sure: `GIT_SSH` is for `git` to use, but here we are talking about how Jenkins uses ssh, and that is through the ssh-agent Jenkins plugin.

Comment: Thanks. i've downgraded the ssh-agent to 1.3, but i can't downgrade the Credentials Plugin, the system will force the version to 1.9.3.
And the build still can't find a suitable ssh-agent provider. Does the version of Credentials Plugin cause the error?

Comment: @user2544979 ok, maybe downgrading the ssh-agent alone is enough.

Comment: @user2544979 darn it, that was my best guest.

Comment: How to downgrade ssh-agent on Windows 8?

Comment: Downgrading is no longer necessary, this should be the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46247455/7571258

Comment: @zett42 Good point. I have updated this 5 years old answer accordingly.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue just by adding `%ProgramFiles%\Git\usr\bin` to the front end of `PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've installed Windows Git on Windows slave, it comes with `ssh-agent` binary (e.g. `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`). Try adding its path to system variable `PATH`.

---

Otherwise untick *SSH Agent* and choose the credentials by selecting *Credentials* from dropdown in *Source Code Management* section.

---

Another way is to generate [personal API token](https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens) ([OAuth](https://help.github.com/articles/git-automation-with-oauth-tokens/)) for that GitHub user and include that along with your repository address, e.g.

```
git clone https://4UTHT0KEN@github.com/foo/bar
```

Comment: [Make sure to insert the path of `ssh-agent` binary **before** the path of Windows own `ssh-agent`](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-51968). The Windows version of `ssh-agent` is incompatible with the SSH Agent plugin. This bite me after replacing the 32-bit Java Runtime that comes with the standard Jenkins installation, with a 64-bit Java Runtime. The 32-bit Java Runtime doesn't show this problem, because Windows's `ssh-agent` is only available in the 64-bit "system32" directory and thus won't be found by 32-bit programs.

Answer (score 0):

For windows, the plugin still requires Tomcat to be installed in both [master and slave](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin).

Comment: No longer required as of SSH Agent plugin 1.14. It can use a "sshagent.exe" that can be found through `PATH` environment variable (e. g. from a Git installation).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I was using an Ubuntu image for the agent, which doesn't have SSH installed.

```
agent {
    docker { image 'ubuntu:focal' }
}
```

... so the solution was as simple as installing SSH as part of the pipeline:

```
steps {
    sh "apt-get update && apt-get install ssh -y"
    // rest of your steps here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was accompanied by an error about disk space depletion:

```
[ssh-agent] FATAL: Could not find a suitable ssh-agent provider
[ssh-agent] Diagnostic report
[ssh-agent] * Exec ssh-agent (binary ssh-agent on a remote machine)
[ssh-agent]     hudson.AbortException: Failed to run ssh-agent: mkdtemp: private socket dir: No space left on device
```

So I ran `docker system prune -a`, which fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

For my case the cause is because I have been using alpine Linux "only", as soon as I switched to, for example, alpine with Ansible, it started working. Obviously because it has SSH client preinstalled.