# running builds on slave nodes gives me Could not find a suitable ssh-agent provider error

Tags: jenkins

When I try to run my build on a slave node using jenkins I get the following error:

```
Could not find a suitable ssh-agent provider
```

Does anyone know why and how I can avoid the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug Jenkins error message "could not find a suitable ssh-agent provider"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348024/how-to-debug-jenkins-error-message-could-not-find-a-suitable-ssh-agent-provider)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Windows slave and SSH Credentials plugin that is because Windows  doesn't provide ssh-agent. If you're using SSH Credentials plugin for provide key to git to check out a repo in comand-line step, you can provide key to git client on each agent (because git have ssh-agent). If your case not that I supposed, you need to follow steps described [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28279) in second comment.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've installed Windows Git on Windows slave, it comes with `ssh-agent` binary (e.g. `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`). Try adding its path to system variable `PATH`.

Alternatively generate [personal API token](https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens) ([OAuth](https://help.github.com/articles/git-automation-with-oauth-tokens/)) for that GitHub user and specify along with your repository address, e.g.

```
git clone https://4UTHT0KEN@github.com/foo/bar
```

Comment: worked for me on windows with Jenkins deployed as WAR